# Install CCNY Computer Vision Stack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like to install the CCNY Computer Vision Stack.

(Link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ccny_vision#Installing)

But I have no folder ros/stacks, so where should I install the stack? I only have a folder "ros-workspace" in my home directory. Should i create there an "stacks" folder?

I am new at this topic, so I hope you can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33911/install-ccny-computer-vision-stack/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your folder `~/ros-workspace` is a perfect place for any stack. As long as a folder is listed in the environment variable `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` it can be anywhere on your system and ROS will find all packages inside this folder.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0